# Apache - multiple websites - allow top folder access

Tags: apache, web, virtualhost

I have multiple websites setup on my Apache2 server.  The directory structure is as follows:

/var/www/

/var/www/site1.com

/var/www/site2.com

It is setup such that "www.site1.com" has root folder /var/www/site1, "www.site2.com" has root folder /var/www/site2,  and   http://server_ip_address  has root folder /var/www

However, if I type  http://server_ip_address/site1.com,  it opens site1.com.  I don't want this to happen.  (That is, individual sites should be accessible only by typing the correct address).

What is the way to configure this. (Also it would be helpful if you could give tips on best practices for directory structures for multiple websites)?

thanks

JP

Answer (score 1):

The [VirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#virtualhost) directive can be used to set individual DocumentRoots for each site name.
Have also a look at this document:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

Answer (score 0):

**Configure multiple websites on Ubuntu**

Create apache configuration file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/site1.com
```

Minimal configuration for the virtual host:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
         DocumentRoot /var/www/site1.com
         ServerName www.site1.com
         # Other directives here
    </VirtualHost>
```

Create the root folder:

```
    sudo mkdir /var/www/site1.com
```

Change the permissions of the folder:

```
    sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/site1.com/
```

Create a new record in /etc/hosts

```
    sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Add the following line:

```
    127.0.0.1       www.site1.com
```

Create a correct symlinks in sites-enabled:

```
    sudo a2ensite site1.com
```

Restart the apache:

```
    sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

You have to do the same with the site2.com, site3.com etc...